# jQuery Mobile <select/> style issue

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Consider the following code:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="name">Car</label> 
    <select data-inline="true" data-theme="b">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select> 
    <span>message</span>           
</div>
```

The output as follows:
[image]

There is a big gap between the component and the message. How can I reduce this gap to a desired amount?

(I tried applying CSS such as `width:100px` to the component, but no success)

**EDIT :**

**Here is the live demo:** http://jsbin.com/icikif/1

Comment: There's no CSS here.  Looks like "message" is floated right, try changing it to left instead.

Comment: Please show the relevant CSS, and consider posting a live [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I did not put any additional CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason can be found in the CSS of jQm:

```
@media (min-width: 450px)
.ui-field-contain .ui-select {
width: 78%;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Add a custom Stylesheet and overwrite the width setting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking for, but if you want the "message" to be closer to the styled select, add this rule in your CSS:

```
.ui-field-contain .ui-select {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

just change `auto` to the desired amount.

Comment: This brings the message closer to the component, but breaks the default styling of fieldcontain container.